# logo made with tikz is bigger in scrlttr2 as in scrartcl

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, koma-script

This is my first question here. From time to time I'm using LaTex to create some documents. Usually I'm able to get an answer from Google if I run into any obstacles. Now I'm unable to find any answers to my problem.

My use-case is to produce a document from 3 separate tex documents which are then viewed in full-page view in a pdf-reader.

My problem is, that the logo which I put on top of each page is slightly bigger when I use `scrlttr2`. So while viewing the document it appears to be jumping.

You can see that the logo circle gets slightly smaller while keeping the red circle size constant by changing to the commented documentclass instead.

```
 \documentclass[DIN, parskip=half]{scrlttr2}
% \documentclass[paper=A4, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text=blue, circle, draw, line width=5pt,font=\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont] { M };
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle [radius=0.9];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My first thoughts were that it has a reason in positioning. But the circle which is drawn around the letter is slightly bigger with scrlttr2.

Any hint on a possible reason is appreciated and might be sufficient to help me to investigate this further.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Please reduce your code as much as possible. Especially the font. Is it needed? I would have to install that font just in order to test so it would be better if you try to make your issue as easy reproducible as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, thanks for the hint. I removed the fonts and now the output shows the effect much clearer because the circle-line became much bigger.

Comment: You are missing a `\selectfont` after the fontsize declaration. So your documents are using different font sizes,

Comment: And you should use `fontsize=11pt` in the letter options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, the \selectfont became necessary after I've removed the font information. Neither that nor setting the fontsize to 11pt helps, unfortunately.

Comment: Fonts do not matter. I still see the difference with `\vrule height1cm width1cm` without any formatting options/macros.

Comment: @percusse thank you very much for your edit. The example is much clearer now. I've just removed the special font to enable those who do not have the font installed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer shame on me `fontsize=11pt` does indeed help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default font size in scrartcl is `11pt`, in scrlttr2 `12pt`, and this matters for nodes as somewhere `em` or `ex` is used. So make sure that you are loading scrlttr2 with the same fontsize option:

```
\documentclass[DIN, parskip=half,fontsize=11pt]{scrlttr2}
```

or scrartcl with larger fontsize:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
```

### Output of scrartcl with default font size (11pt):

[image: scrartcl output]

### Output of scrlttr2 with default font size (12pt):

[image]

### Output of scrlttr2 with 11pt:

[image]

### Output of scrartcl with 12pt:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was late. The following supports Ulrike Fischer's answer.

In `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`, it declares the default

> ```
> \pgfset{
>   inner xsep/.initial     =.3333em,
>   inner ysep/.initial     =.3333em,
> ```

This `em` depends on the default font/font size. In fact, the following test

```
\newdimen\testdimen
\testdimen.3333em
\the\testdimen
```

results in

> 3.9162pt

and

> 3.64961pt

To unify them, assign `inner sep=4pt` explicitly.